# Java Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Mar\\w");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Mary");

String result = m.replaceAll("\\w");
```

The result would ideally be `"y"`. Any ideas?

Comment: It is okay now but the problem was that I didn't know how to "ask Java" what it is using as the \\w. In the above, Java is using \\w to mean the letter 'y'. $1 was the syntax that I needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is not so clear, but I think you want to use a lookahead:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Mar(?=\\w)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Mary");
String result = m.replaceAll("");
```

See it online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/6ercj)

Or you could use a capturing group:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Mar(\\w)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Mary");
String result = m.replaceAll("$1");
```

See it online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/PDtBm)

Comment: Thanks Mark, the second one seems to have done the trick. (Also ideone was a nice touch, haven't seen it before!)